# Apache / nginx Server isn't seeing any AJAX headers at all

Tags: php, ajax, apache, nginx, plesk

Very strange one here and I know I must have done something wrong or set something up incorrectly somewhere but I'm finding it really hard to track down.

My server set up :

```
PHP 7.2
Apache with reverse proxy nginx
Plesk Onyx
ModSecurity 
Fail2Ban
Accepts HTTPS requests only //could this be the problem?
```

My server is refusing to see any AJAX headers. I'm using both `axios` and `pjax` on my front end, both set different AJAX relevant headers, none of them arrive at the server (or are being blocked / filtered) even though I can see them being sent in the browser console.

I obviously don't expect anybody to know the answer here but could you give me some pointers on things to check for, places to look?

I've tried disabling ModSecurity, a whole bunch of different rules for nginx, tried forcing the headers with axios and then dumped vars at the entry point to my custom built PHP framework. I just can't get the requests to show up?

If on the front end `Javascript` I set a custom header this WILL work, for example with `axios` :

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['AXIOS'] = 'true';
```

I will see this on the back end in `PHP`, but if I try to set :

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

This won't.

Another way I can confirm that AJAX request headers aren't being received (or are being blocked somehow) is if I set the Content-Security-Policy header on nginx :

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'";
```

This results in the following in the console for anything content being loaded by `Javascript` via `AJAX` :

```
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”).
```

Without this policy enforced everything works fine, but still no headers.

Could it be Plesk related, HTTPS / HTTP 2 related, PHP related, Apache / nginx related?

I've spent the last 2 days trying to figure this out and I'm running out of ideas.

I'm sorry I know this is a pretty vague and far reaching question in terms of what could be blocking the headers but I just wondered if anybody else had ever experienced anything like this and if so, what they did to rectify it, as I'm kind of at loss here as to where else to look for the cause of this issue.